# Firebase Google OAuth - Auth uid is different from the one returned by the callback for emails that have been previously deleted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have a simple login button that invokes the following code:

```
var ref = new Firebase(<MY_FIREBASE_URL>);

ref.authWithOAuthPopup('google', function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Login Failed!', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Authenticated successfully. ID:', authData.uid);
    }
}, {
    scope: 'email, profile'
});
```

For new users, it creates an entry in the Auth table in Firebase and assigns a UID to it. This UID is **supposed** to be the same as **authData.uid** returned in the callback. However, they are different for user emails that have been previously deleted from the Auth table. Basically, the IDs only match once - for user accounts that have never been stored in the Auth table. If you delete it from Auth and re-do the authentication flow, the ID's will be different.

It appears to me that this is a bug in Firebase's implementation of the unique ID generation algorithm. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any workarounds?

I'm using Firebase SDK 2.4.2.

EDIT: This is not reproducible using SDK 3.

Comment: I guess that's why it's a unique ID, it doesn't seem to me a bug, it's just like generating a random JWT token, to create sessions for your logged in users. :) also try to migrate to the latest firebase 3.x

Comment: The reason I think it's a bug is that this uniqueness only happens on one side - Auth table. The ID that gets returned in authData.uid is consistently the same.
Edit: I will try to get to upgrade to 3, but there are a few things preventing me from doing that. At the moment I'm trying to reproduce this on SDK 3.

Comment: I have the same issue today in 2021: the google sign in token returned by google is different from the one my user have on firebase console. This can't be by design as you won't have any way of identifying that user with the uid.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was wrong: apparently if the sign in process with one of your google account fails and you were already logged in on google with another account, you get logged in / registered on your firebase app with the wrong account. This is definitely a bug .-.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're describing and if so then I believe it is a bug:

1. Create user `A` with email `a`
2. Delete user `A` from the Firebase console
3. Create user `B` with email `a`
4. `authData.uid` for `B` is the same as `A`
5. the `uid` for `B` in the Firebase console is some other random string

What you can do as a work around for now would be to delete the user via the 2.x SDK instead of from the Firebase console.

Comment: This should now be fixed.  The 2.X SDKs should be properly reflecting the same UIDs that are shown in the Auth console.